# Socket.IO + Emoji

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, socket.io

I've been dealing with an emoji issue since several weeks. I've been trying to add emoji to a chat using socket.io.
I have tried CSS emoji, Javascript emoji and so on. I have tried different options but nothing seems to work. I'm kind of desperate because, though I try and play with different options, I don't get the "smilies" to be displayed at all.

Right now I'm using this repository: https://github.com/wedgies/jquery-emoji-picker
I checked the readme, followed the examples and no, didn't work again.

This is my HTML code, the first CSS is the one I use for socket.io

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">




<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.emojipicker.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.emojipicker.js"></script>

  <!-- Emoji Data -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.emojipicker.a.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.emojipicker.a.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

      $('#text-custom-trigger').emojiPicker({
        width: '300px',
        height: '200px',
        button: false
      });

      $('#input-default').emojiPicker();

      $('#input-custom-size').emojiPicker({
        width: '300px',
        height: '200px'
      });

      $('#input-left-position').emojiPicker({
        position: 'left'
      });

      $('#trigger').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#text-custom-trigger').emojiPicker('toggle');
      });

    });
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">

    #emojiPickerWrap {margin:10px 0 0 0;}
    .field { padding: 20px 0; }
    textarea { width: 400px; height: 200px; }
  </style>


</head>
<body>
  <ul class="pages">
    <li class="chat page">
      <div class="chatArea">
        <ul class="messages"></ul>
      </div>
      <input class="inputMessage" id="input-default" placeholder="¿Qué quieres decir?"/>
    </li>
    <li class="login page">
      <div class="form">
        <h3 class="title">Ingresa un nombre de usuario</h3>
        <input class="usernameInput" type="text" maxlength="14" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/main.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I know this is easy, and knowing that is more frustrating. 
I appreciate your help and advices.

Best regards.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please describe your problem in more detail than "didn't work". What, specifically didn't work? The picker? In which case, why is socket.io relevant? You don't have any socket.io-related code in your snippet. (Also, `sockets` tag is something very different - not even available in clientside JS; you probably meant `socket.io`.) Is there an error in the console? Details, man! :)

Comment: What he said, and make a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)! It'll help us investigate.

Comment: @Amadan thanks for replying. I updated a little my code and I added a Fiddle. I'm so sorry I thought I was giving a lot of info already. Anyway, didn't work means that the picker doesn't show up. https://jsfiddle.net/pddjd9re/

Comment: No apologies necessary, and thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks again. So the idea is to join two inputs "class="inputMessage" and class="emojiable-option" together, on my code they don't work separated not mixed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the code that you might have in your development env but from what you have given, I was able to put together a JSFiddle and it seems to work fine for me. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybyayvqm/)
This code seems to show the emoji button just fine - `$('#input-default').emojiPicker();`

Comment: Its not working in yours because you dint load the emoji libraries. If you look at my fiddle, on the left side menu you will see 'External Resources'. If you load the same resources in your fiddle it will work just fine. Also you are not loading jQuery either. Here is your fiddle just updated with proper libraries. [https://jsfiddle.net/pddjd9re/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/pddjd9re/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs without any problems, see the demo below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $('#text-custom-trigger').emojiPicker({
    width: '300px',
    height: '200px',
    button: false
  });

  $('#input-default').emojiPicker();

  $('#input-custom-size').emojiPicker({
    width: '300px',
    height: '200px'
  });

  $('#input-left-position').emojiPicker({
    position: 'left'
  });

  $('#trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#text-custom-trigger').emojiPicker('toggle');
  });

});
```

```css
#emojiPickerWrap {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.field {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/wedgies/jquery-emoji-picker/master/css/jquery.emojipicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/wedgies/jquery-emoji-picker/master/js/jquery.emojipicker.js"></script>

<!-- Emoji Data -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/wedgies/jquery-emoji-picker/master/css/jquery.emojipicker.a.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/wedgies/jquery-emoji-picker/master/js/jquery.emojipicker.a.js"></script>
</head>

<ul class="pages">
  <li class="chat page">
    <div class="chatArea">
      <ul class="messages"></ul>
    </div>
    <input class="inputMessage" placeholder="¿Qué quieres decir?" />
    <input type="text" id="input-default" class="emojiable-option" placeholder="Default">
  </li>
  <li class="login page">
    <div class="form">
      <h3 class="title">Ingresa un nombre de usuario</h3>
      <input class="usernameInput" type="text" maxlength="14" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you see squares instead of the icons, your OS don't have the font that supports these symbols. For example, for Windows 7 you need to install an update [KB2729094](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2729094), see [this article](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20120818/microsoft-backports-windows-8-emoji-for-segoe-ui-symbol-to-windows-7/) for more details.

Also, you're including two copies of jQuery library, remove the older one 1.10.2.

Comment: The idea is to join those two inputs "class="inputMessage" and class="emojiable-option" all together in one line. When I try to do that, it doesn't work.
I'm running Ubuntu. When I try the demo I see the emoji faces.
I removed the old jQuery library.

Comment: Why can't you remove `<input class="inputMessage">`, the other input still allows to enter text and emoji.

Comment: I tried that, it was one of the first things I did when I tested the code.
I took screenshots: http://imgur.com/FyEFOtF so image 1 is the one that works fine and the image 2 is the one which is supposed to have the picker.